# How do I expand an array argument that contains wildcard?

Tags: bash, wildcards

How do I expand an *array* that has a *wildcard* argument? For example, I would like to list all files starting with `a3` :- declaring `a` as `("a1" "a2" "a3*")` doesn't work, but `("a1" "a2" a3*)` works (*expression* vs *string* ?), but is there a better way to do that?

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

touch a1 a2 a31 a32

# list files starting with a3

a=("a1" "a2" "a3*") # fails
a=("a1" "a2" a3*) # works

ls "${a[@]}"

rm a1 a2 a31 a32
```

Comment: I am wondering if this is a legitimate case where I should *not* be double-quoting a value.

Comment: Note that "works" and "fails" is dependent on what you want to do. If you want to run `ls` on a file called (literally) `a3*`, then quoting that string is what you _need_ to do. You don't really say what happens and what you want to happen and what the circumstances are (what files are available in the current directory).

Comment: Thanks, @Kusalananda. I thought the *wildcard* was enough to determine the desired output - but you are right - it is better to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash you can combine different quotes and even unquoted strings in the same "word", so I would probably write `a=("a1" "a2" "a3"*)`. That way, for example if `a` ends up being pulled out as `prefix=a`, you can simply do `a=("${prefix}1" "${prefix}2" "${prefix}3"*)`.